# Error de consulta a BBDD con PDO: Call to undefined method Conexion::prepare()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy haciendo una consulta sencilla a mi BBDD usando PDO. Mi conexión a PDO la tengo almacenada en una clase llamada `Conexion` en un archivo llamado Conexion.php al que mando a llamar para instanciar mi clase.

El problema es que, cuando intento traer los datos de mi base de datos me tira este error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Conexion::prepare() in C:\xampp\htdocs\DAlessaShop.Admin\index.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\DAlessaShop.Admin\index.php on line 9
```

No entiendo porque me da ese error. Ya revisé mi clase y todo y aún no encuentro el error. Adjunto mi archivo con la clase y la porción donde estoy haciendo la consulta:

Conexion.php:

```
<?php

    class Conexion
    {
        function __construct() {
            try {
                session_start();

                $this->conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->DB_SERVER . ';dbname=' . $this->DB_BBDD, $this->DB_USER, $this->DB_PASSWORD, $this->arrayOptions);

                return $this->conexion;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {

                die("Error de conexión " . $e->getMessage() . " en la línea " . $e->getLine());
            }
        }

    // Variables usadas para establecer conexión y las configuraciones pertinentes
        private $DB_SERVER = "localhost";
        private $DB_BBDD = "dalesashop";
        private $DB_USER = "root";
        private $DB_PASSWORD = "";
        public $conexion;
        private $arrayOptions = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'",
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        );
    }

    $conexion = new Conexion();
?>
```

index.php (donde estoy haciendo la consulta):

```
<?php

    include_once 'Models/Conexion.php';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM productos";

    try {
        $con_prep = $conexion->prepare($query);
        $con_prep->execute();

        $productos = $con_prep->fetchAll();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>on line: " . $e->getLine() . "<br>on file: " . $e->getFile());
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu caso, tienes una clase `conexion` con un unico metodo, el constructor. Cuando inicializas un objeto de esa clase, defines dentro de esta una propiedad publica llamada `conexion`.

En el index estas llamando al objeto `conexion` (de tipo `conexion`) y al metodo de esta clase, llamado `prepare`. Esto no es correcto, puesto que este ultimo metodo no existe en la definicion de tu clase.

Tienes dos maneras de solucionarlo:

1. define un metodo `prepare` en tu clase:

   public function prepare($sql) {

   $this->conexion->prepare($sql);

   }

2.- en tu index.php llama a `$conexion->conexion->prepare($sql);`

Comment: ¿No hay alguna manera para que, desde el constructor de mi clase Conexion, retorne un objeto de tipo PDO? que es lo que "se supone" está haciendo la instrucción 'return $this->conexion;' en el método constructor